# Can not properly parse XML file retrieved from SCOPUS API

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to import an XML file downloaded from Scopus using ElementTree python library.

These are two snippets of my actual code, both return the same error:

1)

```
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=au-id(' + author_id + ')&apiKey=' + apiKey_standard    
xml = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

2)

```
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=au-id(' + author_id + ')&apiKey=' + apiKey_standard    
xml = urllib2.urlopen(url)
tree = ET.parse(xml)
```

error:

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

If I print, from snippet 1), `print xml[0]` I get `{`.

It seems that urllib2 read method returns a json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add *&httpAccept=application%2Fatom%2Bxml* parameter to your query to specify the desired format:

```
url = 'https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus?query=au-id(' + author_id + ')&apiKey=' + apiKey_standard + '&httpAccept=application%2Fatom%2Bxml'
```